# Proving strong Urysohn lemma via linear combinations and a table

Tags: general-topology, continuity

I just proved the following:

> Earlier lemma: Let $X$ be normal. There is a continuous function $f:X \to [0,1]$ such that $f^{-1}(0) = A$ if and only if $A$ is a closed $G_{\delta}$ set.

Now I wish to prove this:

> Strong Urysohn Lemma: Let $X$ be normal. There is a continuous function $f:X \to [0,1]$ such that $f^{-1}(0) = A, f^{-1}(1) = B$ if and only if $A, B$ are disjoint closed $G_{\delta}$ sets.

The only if direction is easy. Assume $f$ exists. Disjointness is trivial, and applying the earlier lemma to $f,$ we get that $A$ is a closed $G_{\delta}$ set. Similarly, applying it to $1-f$ gives us $B$ is a closed $G_{\delta}$ set.

The if direction is where I'm having trouble. Naturally, we should let $f, g$ be continuous functions for $A, B$ such that $f^{-1}(0) = A, g^{-1}(0) = B.$ Now we build the following:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\text{Free Space}& A & B & X-(A \cup B) \\ \hline
 f & 0 & >0& >0\\ \hline
 g & >0 & 0 & >0\\ \hline
 1-g & <1 & 1& <1\\ \hline
 fg & 0 & 1& >0\\ \hline
 f(1-g) & 0 & \le 1& (0,1)\\ \hline
\end{array}

If only that $\le 1$ in the last row would be $1,$ then $f(1-g)$ would work. How do I find the right linear combination of $1, f, g, fg$? If this approach is doomed, what am I supposed to do, start over? Any hints or ideas?

Comment: Consider instead $\frac{f}{f+g}$.

Comment: @Mindlack That appears to solve it. How was I supposed to think of that?

Comment: That's not necessarily the only answer. $\frac{f(1-g)}{f(1-g)+g}$ was closer to what you had in mind, I think. The main idea is that you "just" need to play around the formulae, trying to patch their defects. Here, dividing by another function to "flatten" the issues where they occurred is something you could have thought of, given time and patience. Regardless, I think it's a good thing to remember.